# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices

Tags: asp.net-core, npgsql

Exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices, Version=4.1.1.0
```

This only happen when i use .NetCore 1.1 on VS 2017. If i rollnback to .Netcore 1.0 i dont see any of these.

StackTrace :

```
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1](Func`4 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ConnectAsync>d__142.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<RawOpen>d__140.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>d__137.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<AllocateLong>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<OpenAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Comment: You're probably using Npgsql 3.1, can you please give 3.2 a try? The dependency on System.Runtime.InteropServices was removed.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion